# jQuery and switch statement

Tags: jquery, switch-statement

I have a problem with my switch statement (see below) using jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var sc = $(document).scrollTop();
switch (sc) {
case sc > 200:
    $('.row1').fadeIn();
    break;  
case sc > 600: 
    $('.row2').fadeIn();
    break;     
case sc > 1000:  
    $(".row3").fadeIn(); 
}
});
```

The case is when I scroll down 200px, the div tag with the class="row1" should appear. But it does not appear.

Does anyone knows what is the problem with my code?

Thanks

Comment: That's not how switch statements work - use a set of if-else's ... (You could reorder and rewrite this as `switch(true)`... but yuck)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `>` in a switch statement.

Instead use an `if ... else if` chain:

```
var sc = $(document).scrollTop();
if (sc > 1000) {  
    $(".row3").fadeIn(); 
} else if (sc > 600) {
    $('.row2').fadeIn();
} else if (sc > 200) {
    $('.row1').fadeIn();
}
```

NB: note that the conditions are in reverse order, so you get the correct result. If you would keep them in the original order, then the `if (sc > 1000)` would never be true when reached. Such a value for `sc` would have already been treated with the earlier `if (sc > 200)`.

#### Alternative

If you like compact code, you could write this also with a ternary operator and only work on the part that is different, i.e. the number following `row`:

```
$(".row" + (sc > 1000 ? 3 : sc > 600 ? 2 : sc > 200 ? 1 : 0)).fadeIn();
```

This may produce the selector `.row0`, but as that does (should) not exist, nothing will happen in that case.

Comment: and why are they conditions work in reverse order and not the other way?

Comment: @PopPilli, I added more explanation in my answer.

Comment: @trincot  the last code line gave me some new knowledge.Thanks.+1(given at-once you aswered)

Comment: @trincot the ternary operator example is awesome. Thanks :D